# Removing unnecessary <ns0:Messages> and <ns0:Message1> tags from the not well formed XML output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Could you please provide me XSLT logic (either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 version is fine) to convert the below not well formed xml input to well formed XML data.

Input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns0:invoiceOrder xmlns:ns0="http://cts.com"
                   type="ABCD"
                   businessDivision="X0"
                   salesOrganization="XYZ10"
                   Channel="Y0">
            <ns0:references>
                <ns0:key type="Source System">ABC</ns0:key>
                <ns0:relationship scheme="Customer" schemeAgency="APAC" role="Sell to">703760000</ns0:relationship>
                <ns0:document type="Purchase Order">AB123</ns0:document>
            </ns0:references>
            <ns0:notes>
                <ns0:note type="XY67" language="EN">package1</ns0:note>
            </ns0:notes>
            <ns0:orderLines>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">100411</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="credit Amount">274.50</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">140072</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="credit Amount">58.41</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
            </ns0:orderLines>
            <ns0:terms>
                <ns0:term type="Reason Code">D19</ns0:term>
                <ns0:term type="Payment Terms">Y000</ns0:term>
            </ns0:terms>
            <ns0:billingInfo>
                <ns0:paymentMethod/>
            </ns0:billingInfo>
            <ns0:flags>
                <ns0:flag type="1099 Payment Flag">Y</ns0:flag>
            </ns0:flags>
            <ns0:dates>
                <ns0:date type="Proposed Invoice Date">2018-11-02</ns0:date>
            </ns0:dates>
        </ns0:invoiceOrder>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns0:invoiceOrder xmlns:ns0="http://cts.com"
                   type="ABCD"
                   businessDivision="X0"
                   salesOrganization="ABC10"
                   Channel="Y0">
            <ns0:references>
                <ns0:key type="Source System">ABC</ns0:key>
                <ns0:relationship scheme="Customer" schemeAgency="APAC" role="Sell to">702390000</ns0:relationship>
                <ns0:document type="Purchase Order">AB123</ns0:document>
            </ns0:references>
            <ns0:notes>
                <ns0:note type="XY34" language="EN">package2</ns0:note>
            </ns0:notes>
            <ns0:orderLines>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">100411</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="Rebate Amount">76.25</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">140072</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="Rebate Amount">9.74</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
            </ns0:orderLines>
            <ns0:terms>
                <ns0:term type="Reason Code">Y19</ns0:term>
                <ns0:term type="Payment Terms">Y000</ns0:term>
            </ns0:terms>
            <ns0:billingInfo>
                <ns0:paymentMethod/>
            </ns0:billingInfo>
            <ns0:flags>
                <ns0:flag type="1099 Payment Flag">Y</ns0:flag>
            </ns0:flags>
            <ns0:dates>
                <ns0:date type="Proposed Invoice Date">2018-11-02</ns0:date>
            </ns0:dates>
        </ns0:invoiceOrder>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Expected Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns0:invoiceOrder xmlns:ns0="http://cts.com"
                   type="ABCD"
                   businessDivision="X0"
                   salesOrganization="XYZ10"
                   Channel="Y0">
            <ns0:references>
                <ns0:key type="Source System">ABC</ns0:key>
                <ns0:relationship scheme="Customer" schemeAgency="APAC" role="Sell to">703760000</ns0:relationship>
                <ns0:document type="Purchase Order">AB123</ns0:document>
            </ns0:references>
            <ns0:notes>
                <ns0:note type="XY67" language="EN">package1</ns0:note>
            </ns0:notes>
            <ns0:orderLines>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">100411</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="credit Amount">274.50</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">140072</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="credit Amount">58.41</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
            </ns0:orderLines>
            <ns0:terms>
                <ns0:term type="Reason Code">D19</ns0:term>
                <ns0:term type="Payment Terms">Y000</ns0:term>
            </ns0:terms>
            <ns0:billingInfo>
                <ns0:paymentMethod/>
            </ns0:billingInfo>
            <ns0:flags>
                <ns0:flag type="1099 Payment Flag">Y</ns0:flag>
            </ns0:flags>
            <ns0:dates>
                <ns0:date type="Proposed Invoice Date">2018-11-02</ns0:date>
            </ns0:dates>
        </ns0:invoiceOrder>
        <ns0:invoiceOrder xmlns:ns0="http://cts.com"
                   type="ABCD"
                   businessDivision="X0"
                   salesOrganization="ABC10"
                   Channel="Y0">
            <ns0:references>
                <ns0:key type="Source System">ABC</ns0:key>
                <ns0:relationship scheme="Customer" schemeAgency="APAC" role="Sell to">702390000</ns0:relationship>
                <ns0:document type="Purchase Order">AB123</ns0:document>
            </ns0:references>
            <ns0:notes>
                <ns0:note type="XY34" language="EN">package2</ns0:note>
            </ns0:notes>
            <ns0:orderLines>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">100411</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="Rebate Amount">76.25</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
                <ns0:orderLine>
                    <ns0:identifiers>
                        <ns0:identifier scheme="Item" schemeAgency="ABC">140072</ns0:identifier>
                    </ns0:identifiers>
                    <ns0:amounts>
                        <ns0:amount type="Rebate Amount">9.74</ns0:amount>
                    </ns0:amounts>
                </ns0:orderLine>
            </ns0:orderLines>
            <ns0:terms>
                <ns0:term type="Reason Code">Y19</ns0:term>
                <ns0:term type="Payment Terms">Y000</ns0:term>
            </ns0:terms>
            <ns0:billingInfo>
                <ns0:paymentMethod/>
            </ns0:billingInfo>
            <ns0:flags>
                <ns0:flag type="1099 Payment Flag">Y</ns0:flag>
            </ns0:flags>
            <ns0:dates>
                <ns0:date type="Proposed Invoice Date">2018-11-02</ns0:date>
            </ns0:dates>
        </ns0:invoiceOrder>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Would like to have the starting and ending tags only once in the XML output (mentioned above) , so that XML will be well formatted and it will suit my requirement

start tags :

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
```

Corresponding end tags:

```
</ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both. If you're not sure which version your processor supports, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Also how is this different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124256/need-help-to-add-extra-root-nodes-for-not-well-formed-xml-structure ?

Comment: Hello Michael, I can't use XSLT 3.0 version in my processor. I am really grateful for your helpOur processor will allow both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 versions. So I can't use the code which you have provided me earlier.So I thought like , if I myself add the <ns0:message> tags though different XSLT , so that i can look for  the XSLT code  which can remove the <ns0:message> tags in the other places as shown in current output in this thread using XSLT1.0/2.0 
versions.

Comment: Hello Michael, I have got the solution for this..I have tried changing the <ns0:message> logic in my initial XSLT which was generating the source input.It worked.Thanks a lot for your quick support.

Comment: I am afraid you are confused: I haven't provided you with anything earlier. However, Martin Honnen did offer you an XSLT2.0 solution using the `unparsed-text()` function. In any case, you should delete your question here and if necessary, continue the discussion in your other one.

Comment: You refer in the question title to "not well formed XML output", and in the question body to "not well formed XML input". That has me confused. (a) if the files are not well-formed XML, then XSLT is no use to you. However (b) the files look well-formed to me.